# d3.csv - what is being passed into the function?

Tags: csv, d3.js

I've used the .csv method to load data but not sure I fully understand it.

As I see it, it takes two arguments: the file itself and then the function. It's this latter part I am struggling with.

If I have: `d3.csv("file.csv", function(data) {..}`

What is being passed to the function as the 'data' argument?

I'm presuming it's the content of the file but not sure.

Thanks for any pointers - I have read numerous tutorials but none seem to make it clear!

Answer (score 1):

`d3.csv` is a wrapper to an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) which is an asynchronous operation. The function on `d3.csv("file.csv", function(error,data) {..})` is a callback function that will be called when the `XMLHttpRequest` completes.

According to [d3 v3 documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Requests.md#send) the callback should have 2 parameters:

```
d3.csv("file.csv", function(error,data) {
   //Callback
});
```

The parameter `error` is used for handling  errors and is `null` when the operations is successful. The paraneter `data` has the request response only when the request is successful.

Comment: `d3.csv` callback works just fine with only 1 parameter. When you read an API, parameters inside a square bracket (like `[foo]`) are *optional*.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that it is asynchronous and the callback. My questions is, what are the arguments error and data? Variables? If so, what is passed into data?

Comment: As Gerardo said, you can just include the single data argument.. so I'm confused as to what that is?

Comment: If there is only one argument, it will be the`data` with the request response.

Comment: Thanks. So if the file has no errors, the csv values are passed into 'data' in, for example, function(data){}